# No query results for model [App\Models\Favourite]

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $bar = Favourite::findOrFail($id);
    $bar->where('bar_id', $id)->delete();

}
```

- I am getting this error 'No query results for model [App\Models\Favourite].', when i am trying delete value with this query.
  -

Comment: Is there a Favourite in your database with the `id` value you're passing? There appears to be some confusion in your code whether the data's in `bar_id` or just `id`.

Comment: here  is my Favourite model                                                          `class Favourite extends Model
{
    
    protected $fillable = ['bar_id', 'users_id'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public function bar() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bar');
    }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `findOrFail` it means if it dosen't get a result it will throw an exception, as [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) says you will get this exception:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException
>
> Message:
>   No query results for model [App\Models\Favourite]

So the right way to do it on the controller should be:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException; //Import exception.

try {
  Favourite::destroy($id);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
  // Handle the error.
}
```

Another way to do it is like this on the model:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Favourite::find($id)->delete();
}
```

But you need to control what happens when the Model is not found.

Comment: i trying but i getting this error " Call to a member function delete() on nul"'

Comment: This is because the model is not found.

Comment: Don't forget to add the model with use \App\Favorite; at the top of your controller

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the problem will be in the destroy params
for example, my problem was

```
public function destroy(Room $room)
{
      //....
}
```

my problem was that I send data to the function but not respecting the number in paramerts
so it throws me the same error that you talking about

so my solution was to add params that I suppose to send

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
     //....
}
```